# Write Test Cases For Protected Method

Tags: java, methods, junit, easymock

i am new in unit testing. please help me how to write a  test cases for protected method using Junit and easy mock .

Answer (score 2):

You could keep the same package name for your test class as that of the class under test. That way if your class under test say `MyClass.java` is in `src` directory with package name `com.abc.mypackage` then you your test class say `MyClassTest.java` could be in `test` directory with same package name. See image below:

[image]